# How do I activate my hotspot on my prepaid service I had on postpaid?

Tags: ios, wifi, tethering, cellular-data

My iPhone used to work for tethering when I had a postpaid account.

Now that I am on a prepaid plan, I need my hotspot back ASAP to use my optus service for my laptop.

Please tell me I can still acsess my Intrenet tethering as I need it or my laptop is useless to me. I was on a plan and I have now as of yesterday changed from dodo to Optus pre paid.

Can u suggest how I can activate the same service to use my laptop through my mobile phone service?

Comment: Does this involve an Apple product in some way? It sounds more like a question for your cell phone provider.

Comment: Yes sorry.  I didn't specify I am using my iPhone 4 to my compaq laptop

Comment: U may be right i was trying to re activate it but whatever I do seems to be something to do with my provider.    Optus I assumed would hv an option as Telstra does to access my hotspot :-(